# how to mount a directory from another server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I have two Ubuntu servers. One of them has a directory with data. I want this directory to be visible (and writable) by the second server. How can I do this? What tool to use?

Comment: If only this didn't exist; http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/?cb=1 ... You already have the NFS tag in your question, have you thought of doing any form of basic self-help so far, maybe looking up what NFS is and how it's used, it's very simple basic stuff that professional sysadmins really could do with knowing

Answer (score 29, accepted):

On the 'server' add an entry into your [`/etc/exports`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports)  to share the directory e.g.

```
/directory/with/data secondserver.tld(rw)
```

which allows secondserver read/write access to the `directory/with/data`

then use [exportfs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/exportfs) to share the directory

```
exportfs -r
```

and you can verify your export with

```
exportfs
/directory/with/data    secondserver.tld
```

You can now [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) your directory on secondserver

```
mount server:/directory/with/data /mnt
```

and you can verify the mount

```
mount -t nfs
server:/directory/with/data on /mnt type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.254.196)
```

You may want to add an entry to your [fstab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) to have it mount on boot too

```
server:/directory/with/data /mnt    nfs rw 0 0
```

You'll probably want to read the various man pages I linked to too.

Comment: Note: I needed to restart the first server after installing exportfs and running exportfs -r.

Comment: That wouldn't be normal.